# "gdm -v" failed : failed to acquire org.gnome.DisplayManager

Tags: suse, gdm

I am using SUSE Enterprise 11 SP3 and I want to check the version of gdm using:

```
localhost:~ # gdm --version
```

But I got an error:

```
** (gdm:5398): WARNING **: Failed to acquire org.gnome.DisplayManager

** (gdm:5398): WARNING **: Could not acquire name; bailing out
```

I am using root to execute this command.

When I try this command in CentOS6.6 or RedHat, it works well.

Does anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstall it or the desktop packages you tried to install it through e.g. tasksel